# Find the nearest date stored in another table according to several "master date", data in common but no ID in common

Tags: mysql, datetime, left-join

Sorry for the title, this was quite hard to explain this in few words (that shows that I don't understand the problem completely).

```
Service Table: (there are other field but not relevant here)
-------------------------------
| PK1    | REF     | Ops_Date |
-------------------------------
| 1      | ABCD    | 20180211 |
| 2      | EFGH    | 20180315 |
| 3      | ABCD    | 20180412 |
-------------------------------

Dim Table: 
-------------------------------
| PK2    | REF     | Arrival  |
-------------------------------
| 57     | ABCD    | 20180108 |
| 58     | ABCD    | 20180201 |
| 59     | EFGH    | 20180309 |
| 60     | EFGH    | 20180311 |
| 61     | ABCD    | 20180409 |
| 62     | ABCD    | 20180411 |
-------------------------------

Result:
--------------------------------------------------------
| PK1    | REF     | Ops_Date | PK2      | Arrival     |       
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1      | ABCD    | 20180211 | 58       | 20180201    |
| 2      | EFGH    | 20180315 | 60       | 20180311    | 
| 3      | ABCD    | 20180412 | 62       | 20180411    |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

What I need is a left join of the service table with the dim table.
The criterias ON are the REF which is common to both and then the nearest arrival from the ops_date.
The ops date will always be after the arrival, that's what I need always the nearest before the ops_date.

What I try :

```
   SELECT 
      PK1, 
      REF,
      ops_date, 
      PK2, 
      arrival

   FROM 
     service 

   LEFT JOIN dim
   ON service.REF = dim.REF
```

*I suppose that a condition should be added here to manage to find the nearest date for each record during the Left join*

I'm not sure this kind of think are even possible without any ETL or procedures but if anybody have a clue It would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a condition to your `JOIN` that says that the `Arrival` time in `Dim` is the maximum `Arrival` time that is less than the associated `Ops_Date` value for that `Service`. You can find that result with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s.*, d.PK2, d.Arrival
FROM Service s
LEFT JOIN Dim d ON d.REF = s.REF 
               AND d.Arrival = (SELECT MAX(Arrival)
                                FROM Dim d2
                                WHERE d2.REF = s.REF
                                  AND d2.Arrival < s.Ops_Date)
```

Output:

```
PK1 REF     Ops_Date    PK2 Arrival
1   ABCD    20180211    58  20180201
2   EFGH    20180315    60  20180311
3   ABCD    20180412    62  20180411
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vWQLa84xrxmxxmxTjs7EeW/0)

Comment: Thanks Nick, I add the part with the MAX value too but I couldn't manage to put it the right way within the Left Join.